# HTML number doesn't work for Registered trade mark symbol 

Tags: java, character-encoding, special-characters

How to display registered trademark symbol ® unix environment. In this symbol working in window environment, but it not working unix environment.I am having paragraph in java file.displaying this symbol when working in windows environment, but move to unix(server) symbol not displaying in the format(®).

```
String str="stackoverflow® ",getspechars();
getspechars()
{
  .......
  SpeChars.put("®", "&#174;");
}
```

when executing string with special characters get the reference from another method. Here I tried encoding "\u00AE" instead of ®.

Both are getting failed. Please suggest me how to get the trademark symbol?

```
DEC OCT HEX BIN      Symbol HTML   Number  HTML Name Description 
174 256 AE  10101110 ®      &#174; &reg;   Registered trade mark sign)
```

these signs will work ?

What is the problem here?

When sending email from window system that email displaying correct format. But not unix system.

Example:

```
original message="stackoverflow ®"
Getting email message="stackoverflow ÿ"
```

What is the reason behind in this ?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an encoding problem to me. If you're editing files on Windows, they're saved as the platform default (I think [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) aka Cp1252), not UTF-8.

Make sure that you're using UTF-8 end to end.

#### Obligatory Joel On Software link

[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: Also, using the entity (&reg;) rather then the character code is likely to work in a more encoding independent way.

Comment: @Fredrik: not sure I agree with that. The numeric value in the reference (&#174;) is not related to the document's encoding and so should work the same anywhere.

Comment: @Matthew Wilson you're probably right although I would still consider the named version more likely to work whenever if there is a difference. It is also a lot more readable when looking at the source.